# Calculating energies in Coulomb regime, is there an equivalent to the Fourier transform for free space?

Tags: electromagnetism, nuclear-physics, computational-physics

In free space, one can find the energy decomposition of a wavefunction by using Fourier transform. Is there an equivalent common transformation to do this for a wavefunction in a Coulomb potential? Say into Coulomb wavefunctions? If so, is this easy to implement computationally on a grid?

For context, I have been working on code to time-dependently simulate nuclear reactions on a spacial grid. I currently calculate the component energies of a wavefunction in zero potential using the Fast Fourier Transform. I can propagate the wavefunction out to a decent distance where the Coulomb potential is weak, and then calculate the energies as per usual (introducing some small error), but this is extremely time consuming. Having a method which works in a Coulomb potential will mean I only need to wait until the wavefunction is outside the Coulomb barrier, saving a lot of time and improving the accuracy.